# How did Rudy know where to leave the body parts when Dexter was on his date with Rita?

Tags: plot-explanation, dexter

In the first episode of the first season, 25 minute in, Dexter leaves Rita during their date to see what is going on with a crime scene.  The police are at the location where the remains of another Ice Truck Killer's victim was left. Since Rudy seems to leave little to chance, how would he know to leave the body parts near where Dexter would be going on the date?  Was that explained at all?

Comment: Don't want to spoil the ending if you didn't completed S1, but there is a special connection between Dexter and Rudy ; if we assume Rudy was aware of Dexter's whereabouts and that the date lasted long enough, then Rudy had enough time to prepare the scene. In the the first episode, there is no explanation about the Dexter-Rudy connection (voluntarily), and that coincidence (date/crime scene) can seem to be too much...

Comment: @e2-e4 I've completed the entire series. I know Rudy broke into Dexter's apartment to look at the photographs that he used to select other locations to leave the body parts. It seemed improbable to me that Rudy would be able to arrange the body parts on a walkway next to a festival where Dexter and Rita were without being noticed, and with enough time for it to be reported to the police, and for them to respond on the scale they did, that the Police yellow caution tape was up. It seems like the timing is too perfect for a show that went to great pains to make everything plausible.

Comment: @e2-e4 My comment above makes me wonder about the first location shown where Rudy left the body parts. Other than Debra working at the no-tell hotel, I can see no reason for picking that location, and I don't understand if it is connected to Debra. It also seems odd that Rudy could transport and arrange the body parts at a later hour of the day without being noticed at a location like that.